# Accessing complex js object

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have the following JSON object that I receive from an API endpoint, how do I access description property of this object - "description" : "Dorian Market 1"?

```
let markets = { 
  "result":[
     {
      "townId" : "MEBD",
      "storeId" : "1",
      "address" : "Presernova 1",
      "description" : "Dorian Market 1",
      "minOrderValue" : "500",
      "notes" : ""
   } 
      ,
        {
      "townId" : "MEBD",
      "storeId" : "1",
      "address" : "Presernova 2",
      "description" : "Dorian Market 2 ",
      "minOrderValue" : "500",
      "notes" : ""
   } 
       ]
}
```

Is this the right way. markets.result[0].description, is this the right way?

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: The `markets` variable refers to an object with a property called `result` (`markets.result`) which refers to an array. The information you want is in the first entry (`markets.result[0]`), which is an object, in the description property (`markets.results[0].description`). If you needed to search for it (e.g., in case it's not in the first entry), you'd probably want to use `find` on `markets.result`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the right way to access the `description` property of the first element of the `result` array is using `markets.result[0].description`.

```js
let markets = {
  "result":[
    {
      "townId" : "MEBD",
      "storeId" : "1",
      "address" : "Presernova 1",
      "description" : "Dorian Market 1",
      "minOrderValue" : "500",
      "notes" : ""
    },
    {
      "townId" : "MEBD",
      "storeId" : "1",
      "address" : "Presernova 2",
      "description" : "Dorian Market 2 ",
      "minOrderValue" : "500",
      "notes" : ""
    }
  ]
};

console.log(markets.result[0].description)
```

Comment: We have [a canonical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json) for this. Please vote to close rather than posting additional answers. You can always comment to help the OP apply the information from the other question's answers.